# Compare the triplet rows together and select max of them?

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider the following time series data

```
10-5-8-20-30-15-20-2-14-6-50-20-30-60-25-15-0-4-2-8-10-15-12-40-20
```

These are the values of **y**, and the **x** column starts from 1 respectively.

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Z_AXIS" (X NUMBER, Y NUMBER)
```

I have come to the conclusion that if the data in the y-column are *compared three by three*, the maximum value in each triad, is the peak point.

Does anyone have an idea how to specify peak points without using cursor, loop, lead and lag?

Comment: Please define "peak points".

Comment: Do you need to check if either **end** of the series is a peak? For example, if the time series is 8-3-5-2-5 then the very first value is a "peak" - or is it not? Note that both answers given so far will not consider this to be a "peak".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that a given `y` value is larger than the `y` values on the previous or next row *and* your `x` values are really sequential with no gaps (as your question specifies), then you just want a `join`:

```
select z.*
from z_axis z join
     z_axis z_prev
     on z_prev.x = z.x - 1 join
     z_axis z_next
     on z_next.x = z.x + 1
where z.y > z_prev.y and z.y > z_next.y;
```

Answer (score 4):

[MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm#DWHSG8956) was designed for such scenarios:

```
SELECT *
FROM Z_AXIS
MATCH_RECOGNIZE
(
   ORDER BY X
   MEASURES    MATCH_NUMBER() AS match_num,
               CLASSIFIER() AS var_match
   ALL ROWS PER MATCH
   PATTERN ( PEAK )
   DEFINE
        PEAK AS      PEAK.Y > PREV(PEAK.Y) 
                AND  PEAK.Y > NEXT(PEAK.Y)
) mr;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2dc0bc54f4add9671fa3624b12e5cffa)**

Output:

```
         X  MATCH_NUM VAR_MATCH             Y
---------- ---------- ------------ ----------
         5          1 PEAK                 30
         7          2 PEAK                 20
         9          3 PEAK                 14
        11          4 PEAK                 50
        14          5 PEAK                 60
        18          6 PEAK                  4
        22          7 PEAK                 15
        24          8 PEAK                 40
```

Peak is defined as:

```
Y > prev value and Y > next value
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` then you can find the answer using analytic functions without any self-joins (assuming that you do not have an arbitrary self-imposed restriction to not use `LAG` or `LEAD`):

```sql
SELECT x, y
FROM   (
  SELECT x,
         y,
         LAG(y)  OVER (ORDER BY x) AS prev_y,
         LEAD(y) OVER (ORDER BY x) AS next_y
  FROM   z_axis
)
WHERE y > prev_y AND y > next_y;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT x, y
FROM   (
  SELECT x,
         y,
         MAX(y) OVER (ORDER BY x RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS prev_y,
         MAX(y) OVER (ORDER BY x RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS next_y
  FROM   z_axis
)
WHERE y > prev_y AND y > next_y;
```

Which, for the sample data, both output:

> | X | Y |
> | --- | --- |
> | 5 | 30 |
> | 7 | 20 |
> | 9 | 14 |
> | 11 | 50 |
> | 14 | 60 |
> | 18 | 4 |
> | 22 | 15 |
> | 24 | 40 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=be92e81fecc6d848c6ebac074ddaa02e)*